# flask-sqlalchemy filter multiple column using single table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table `Attendee_Handshake` which has 2 column `from_id` and `to_id`, I want to query all the row where the `from_id` and `to_id` has `status` column equal to 0 which is reference on another table `Attendee_Login` where `from_id` and `to_id` is the primary key.

Attendee_Handshake

- `from_id(foreign key)`
- `to_id(foreign key)`

Attendee_Login

- `login_id(primary key)`
- `status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need 2 separate references to `Attendee_Login`, you need an alias:

```
attendee_alias = db.aliased(Attendee_Login)
```

Then it's a simple matter of joining and filtering:

```
Attendee_Handshake.query.\
    join(Attendee_Login, Attendee_Login.login_id == Attendee_Handshake.from_id).\
    join(attendee_alias, attendee_alias.login_id == Attendee_Handshake.to_id).\
    filter(Attendee_Login.status == 0,
           attendee_alias.status == 0)
```